# Responsive images not appearing as they should for mobile

Tags: html, css

Having a problem displaying responsive images for mobile. There are 6 separate images on 1 line for website but for mobile images appear as 2 images on 1 line then 1 image on next line then 2 images on next line and 1 image on final  line.  When I hover over 1st image on mobile all images appear as they should 2 images on 3 lines, tried everything to fix this but can't. I've added HTML and CSS code below.

```
enter code here

<div class="col-md-10">
<div class="xtx">
<a href="x"> <img src=".png"  class="pull-left img-responsive" alt="" width="150" height="150"></a>

<a href="x"> <img src=".png"  class="pull-left img-responsive" alt="" width="150" height="150"></a>

<a href="x"> <img src=".png"  class="pull-left img-responsive" alt="" width="150" height="150"></a>

<a href="x"> <img src=".png"  class="pull-left img-responsive" alt="" width="150" height="150"></a>

<a href="x"> <img src=".png"  class="pull-left img-responsive" alt="" width="150" height="150"></a>

<a href="x"> <img src=".png"  class="pull-left img-responsive" alt="" width="150" height="150"></a>
 </div>
```

﻿﻿    /* Extra small devices (phones, less than 768px) */
    /* No media query since this is the default in Bootstrap */
    /* Small devices (tablets, 768px and up) */
    @media (min-width: @screen-sm-min) { ... }

```
/* Medium devices (desktops, 992px and up) */
@media (min-width: @screen-md-min) { ... }

/* Large devices (large desktops, 1200px and up) */
@media (min-width: @screen-lg-min) { ... }
.body{
background-color:#fff;
}
.fdr img{
float:left;
margin:1%;
background-color: #fff;
border-radius: 5px;
clear: right; 
-webkit-transition: margin 0.5s ease-out; 
-moz-transition: margin 0.5s ease-out; 
-o-transition: margin 0.5s ease-out; 
}
.fdr img:hover{
margin-top:0.1%;
}
.img-responsive{
display:block;
margin:auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try adding the meta on the head tag

```
<html>
    <head>
        <lang="en">
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    </head>
```

Comment: Thanks but already added <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title></title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0"/>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="robots" content="index,follow">